# Why sleeping on the main thread is required to run Camel example

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

I am new to Camel and I'm trying to understand how it works.

I tried the following example:

```
public class CamelMainTest {

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
            CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
            context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                public void configure() {
                    from("file:d:\\inbox\\json?noop=true").to("file:d:\\outbox");
                }
            });
            context.addRoutes(getFileRoute());
            context.start();
    //      Thread.sleep(50000);
            context.stop();

}
```

I'm copying a file from one location to another, but it fails.

When I remove the comment from the line `Thread.sleep(50000);` then it works fine.

Can any one explain why sleeping on the main thread is required?

Comment: Do you mean it works fine when `Thread.sleep(50000);` is not commented?

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? Also, do you realise `Thread.sleep(50000)` puts the program to sleep for 50 seconds?  So when you run it, it will take nearly a minute before it exits.

Comment: @Octopus `Thread.sleep(50000);` commented means statement is not part of execution 

 @Trisha it fails to copy file from one location to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this FAQ from the Camel website

- http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone.html

And the link it refers to such as

- http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

And read the javadoc of the start method of the CamelContext API

- http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html

Comment: thanks @Claus Ibsen i use this site and run example correctly
but here Main class is used and main class has HangupSupport which has support of thred so it works.

Answer (score 2):

I think `CamelContext` runs as a separate thread. If you comment out `Thread.sleep(50000);` then `context` will `start()` and immediately `stop()` causing it to throw error?

In case of `Thread.sleep(50000);` context will `start()` and while the main thread is sleeping, `context` will finish the job as spawned thread and then `stop()`

Comment: yes @sanbhat initially i think that but main thread always waits for termination of it's child thread
correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes.. but you are explicitly calling `stop()` which terminates child thread. `Thread.sleep(5000)` in main gives the child thread scope to run

Comment: I agree with sanbhat. If you start the camel context in a UI (or) web app, you dont need to make the main thread sleep. Here you are putting main thread to sleep, coz you dont have any other work to do here. Start another thread (or) do some process. Meanwhile the camel context will finish its work.

Comment: if i also remove `context.stop();` then also it fails to copy file

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `camel-spring-jar`, here's how you do it: -

```
import org.apache.camel.spring.Main;

/**
 * Main class that boot the Camel application
 */
public final class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.run(args);
    }
}
```

Note that `Main` is imported from `org.apache.camel.spring`, not from the usual `org.apache.camel.main`.

[Reference](https://people.apache.org/%7Edkulp/camel/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html)